# .htaccess entry for redirecting to a folder without showing the folder name in url

Tags: apache, .htaccess

my website resides in public_html/rhf folder.
1. i want if some one enter url https://rhf.in , it should be redirected to https://rhf.in/rhf in background and browser should display only https://rhf.in

2. also for if some one enters http://rhf.in or http://www.rhf.in it should redirected to https://rhf.in/rhf and shows only https://rhf.in/ in browser address bar.

first case is working fine for me by adding following in .htaccess

RewriteRule !^rhf/ /rhf%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

But second case is not working

Kindly help in this regard

Comment: I fail to understand how that rewriting rule you posted should work, but OK, if it works for you...

Comment: The "second case" doesn't work because you have not implemented any such redirection.

Comment: @arkascha first one working. I didn't write the second one. i tried so many.. but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the classical setup:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,END]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/rhf(?:/|$)
RewriteRule ^ /rhf%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,END]
```

For the first redirection to http you obviously need to listen and react to the unencrypted http protocol at all. This implements a *general* redirection. In case you only want to redirect for that specific path you mentioned, the rule would have to be extended by a condition as well.

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: how to redirect http:// www.example.com' to  'https ://example.com' along with the above code

Comment: @CAREHF The first rewriting rule above does exactly that. So I fail to understand your comment...

Comment: but redirected url contains www. i have to remove www from host name

Comment: Ah, I understand, I did not spot that detail before, sorry. Do you really have to do that? Why? If your http server actually responds to both host names, why is that an issue? But anyway, there are three strategies for this, we'd have to decide the strategy first. How are these http hosts defined? Using a `ServerAlias` directive, if so what is the `ServerName`? If not, is that a default host responding to those requests? Or an expicit virtual host?

Comment: i am using hostinger shared hosting. For SEO i have to redirect all the request(www and non-www) to same URL. Thank You so much for your support. I have accomplished it with following .htaccess entry.
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,QSA,END]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,END]



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/nhfr(?:/|$)
RewriteRule ^ /nhfr%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,END]